# Version compare

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have around 2000+ sites maintaining different version of an in-house application which runs Oracle11g.

A table has a parameter which maintains the versions. COl_1 with values like `5.2.4 or 6.86 or 7.2.0.1` etc. I need to compare two sites versions like (`6.2.3` of `site1` is greater than `site2` which might be `6.8`). The datatype is Varchar2.

What is the easiest way? Is there anything built in? Based on the result I have to execute few inserts & merges.

So, how to compare `5.2.4 > 6.2.1.4` in oracle sql query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know maximum version parts count? So, I ask dots count?

Comment: And according to your example it should be 6.2.1.4 > 5.2.4 ?

Comment: max 3 dots. But some will have 2 digits (6.3.95). Yes, 5.2.4 < 6.2.1.4 what I meant was site1.col1 > site2.col1? Thanks

Comment: In normal usage version `6.8` would be greater than `6.2.3` because the convention is that the trailing characters indicate patches (or whatever), so version `6.8` must be later than `6.2`. Obviously people have waded in with answers anyway, but for future reference next time you ask  a question please ensure your examples are correct, complete and consistent. This is especially important if your rules do actually deviate from general conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can split string containing versions into individul parts using the below query, then you can sort and compare records.

```
SELECT x,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 1)) As x_1,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 2)) As x_2,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 3)) As x_3,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 4)) As x_4,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 5)) As x_5,
       to_number(regexp_substr( x, '\d+', 1, 6)) As x_6
FROM table123
order by 
    2 nulls first,
    3 nulls first,
    4 nulls first,
    5 nulls first,
    6 nulls first,
    7 nulls first
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60df0/4

```
|          X | X_1 | X_2 |    X_3 |    X_4 |    X_5 |    X_6 |
|------------|-----|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      1.1.1 |   1 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     1.1.15 |   1 |   1 |     15 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      2.7.1 |   2 |   7 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     2.7.10 |   2 |   7 |     10 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     3.1..1 |   3 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      4.1.1 |   4 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      6.4.2 |   6 |   4 |      2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|        9.1 |   9 |   1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      9.1.2 |   9 |   1 |      2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     9.1.10 |   9 |   1 |     10 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 10.1.1.2.4 |  10 |   1 |      1 |      2 |      4 | (null) |
|     15.1.3 |  15 |   1 |      3 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     21.1.1 |  21 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     23.1.2 |  23 |   1 |      2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|    23.1.10 |  23 |   1 |     10 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     30.1.1 |  30 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|     31.1.1 |  31 |   1 |      1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       41.1 |  41 |   1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can left-pad the major, minor and patch versions and concatenate them and compare the total strings:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN lpad(regexp_substr( '6.2.1.4', '\d+', 1, 1),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr( '6.2.1.4', '\d+', 1, 2),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr( '6.2.1.4', '\d+', 1, 3),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr( '6.2.1.4', '\d+', 1, 4),10,'0') < 
        lpad(regexp_substr( '5.2.4', '\d+', 1, 1),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr('5.2.4', '\d+', 1, 2),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr('5.2.4', '\d+', 1, 3),10,'0')
      ||lpad(regexp_substr( '5.2.4', '\d+', 1, 4),10,'0')
    THEN 'LESS'
    ELSE 'NOT LESS'
  END
FROM dual;
```

The solution allows for each part; major version , minor version etc. to be up to 10 digits long. Of course you can also compare using the greater '>' operator.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am bit late to the party, but I found a very easy solution to compare versions in Oracle. Just need to make compare versions as **varchar** and compare.

Check the following simple query and tested it for different versions and it worked!!!

```
select case when '1.0.30' < '1.1.22' then 'true' else 'false' end as isVersionHigher
from dual;

--Result => 'true'
```

You can even compare versions just having major and minor digits. Check below query.

```
select case when '1.0' < '1.1.22' then 'true' else 'false' end as isVersionHigher
from dual;

--Result => 'true'
```

Comment: That doesn't work when the version numbers can have different numbers of digits. For example, this query gives a `false` result: `select case when '1.0.3' < '1.0.22' then 'true' else 'false' end as isVersionHigher from dual;`